# Database first, files extensions and their uses

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio

When I use the wizard to generate the codes, it will also generate the following file extensions:

1. xxxx.edmx
2. xxxx.Designer.cs
3. xxxx.edmx.diagram
4. xxxx.tt

What are the purposes of all these files? Can I remove them? (If I'm not mistaken, in code-first approach, I really need the .cs classes only.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc982042(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Have you looked through the contents of each file? It will certainly give you a clue.

Comment: Yes, I did, but most of them do not make any sense to me. There is even one file with comments only.

Comment: They are all auto-generated files, and you shouldn't have to worry about what they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**.tt** is [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) file which generates your Entity Classes and Context.

**.edmx.diagram** contains information that is used by the Entity Designer to render a graphical display of the conceptual model.

**.Designer.cs** contains information that is used by the Entity Designer to render a conceptual model graphically and to define some conceptual model and design-time properties. after vs 2012 this file is usually useless and T4 code generators are used by default.

**.edmx** is an XML file that defines a conceptual model, a storage model, and the mapping between these models